# Where vs. In places where

Tags: meaning, redundancy

> - He built cathedrals in places where there were no cathedrals. *The New Yorker*
> - Many Medicare patients live in places where only one H.M.O. *The New York Times*
> - What is the trait you most deplore in others? Sticking chewing gum in places where other people find it. *The Guardian*, an interview

What is the reason to use *in places where* instead of just *where*?

Comment: Probably because it emphasises "places". In the 'fused' construction, "where" also means "in places where", but it's no so obvious.

Comment: Because they are journalists and have to fill the page?